# VBA - Reorder Access 2010 Navigation Form Tab Index

Tags: ms-access, navigation, vba

Is there a way to dynamically reorder the navigation buttons on the Access 2010 Navigation Form?

I would like to hide certain buttons depending on user type; however simply hiding them leaves a gap between buttons if the order cannot be modified.

I have tried similar to the following with no luck.

```
Me.NavigationButton1.TabIndex = 1  
Me.NavigationButton2.TabIndex = 0

Me.Requery 
Me.Refresh
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

NavigationButtons work a bit differently. They are managed in a `NavigationControl` container that does not resize automatically if underlying buttons are hidden.

However, you can try this, it works for me:

```
' Always remember the normal size of the button '
Static bt1Witdh as Long
if bt1Width = 0 then bt1Width = Me.NavigationButton1.Width

' Now hide the button '
Me.NavigationButton1.Width = 0
Me.NavigationButton1.Visible = False  

' Unhide the button '
Me.NavigationButton1.Visible = true  
Me.NavigationButton1.Width = bt1Width
```

You can make this a lot more generic and a bit 'hacky' by using the control's `Tag` property as a temporary storage for keeping track of their normal width:

```
Public Sub HideNavigationButton(bt As NavigationButton)
    ' Store the width if we haven't already done so '
    If bt.Tag = vbNullString Then bt.Tag = CStr(bt.Width)

    bt.Width = 0
    bt.Visible = False
End Sub

Public Sub ShowNavigationButton(bt As NavigationButton)
    If bt.Visible Or bt.Width > 0 Then Exit Sub

    bt.Visible = True
    bt.Width = CInt(bt.Tag)
End Sub
```

To use it:

```
' Hide '
HideNavigationButton Me.NavigationButton1

' Show '
ShowNavigationButton Me.NavigationButton1
```